# SQLPro read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I am getting this error when trying to use SQL pro to get into a remote DB. It works every now and then and not sure whats going on.

I have also run into this issue with GIT now where it asks for my passphrase.

I have updated permissions on dev/tty, tried deleting `known_hosts`, check permissions on `~/ssh/` and added `authorized_keys` file. Nothing works.

Error:

```
Used command:  /usr/bin/ssh -v -N -S none -o ControlMaster=no -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=3 -i /Users/PackyTagliaferro/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -o TCPKeepAlive=no -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 -p 22 forge@107.170.236.120 -L 58527:127.0.0.1:3306 -L 58528:107.170.236.120:3306

OpenSSH_7.3p1, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Control socket " none" does not exist
debug1: Connecting to 107.170.236.120 [107.170.236.120] port 22.
debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/PackyTagliaferro/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/PackyTagliaferro/.ssh/id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 107.170.236.120:22 as 'forge'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Th+2puoVypXAN0yQ1t09AHbmnssBxkoRP+4Hl9dIJcI
debug1: Host '107.170.236.120' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/PackyTagliaferro/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/PackyTagliaferro/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 501
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 501
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 501
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Hi there -- I experience this issue as well. Could you perhaps explain what you did with permissions on dev/tty, known_hosts, etc? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47777180/sequelpro-read-passphrase-cant-open-dev-tty-device-not-configured

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I met this problem too when use SqlPro to connect the remote sql.

- Firstly, you should confirm that you public key has been added into the Linux server, guess you have done this.
- Secondly, this is the most import step. Please load the private key file `id_rsa` not the `id_rsa.pub`

[image: Screenshot]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This worked. Not sure what's the difference but only the non .pub file works.